# When will I get rewards for joining the Oceanic server?

Tags: league-of-legends

On the LoL home screen it said that there would be rewards for anyone who joined the server in Oceania. I don't seem to have gotten anything or any notifications for it. Now that I've joined Oceania I can't get back to NA without spending rp. Btw I live in Australia but would rather play on NA servers.

People have been telling me that I would get the rewards when beta ends but beta has already ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.surrenderat20.net/2013/06/oceania-servers-now-in-beta.html%E2%80%8E/%22This%22) post says that the rewards (assuming you mean Ziggs and his pool party skin) will be received after the PAX event, which is late July.